# Cognos report has no data whereas database has records

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I created a list report with 7-8 prompt selection as required. While selecting the necessary prompts and generated the report. It ended up with "No data available".
Whereas the SQL database has records for the same selection.
Please help to find the cause of this issue!?

Thanks

Comment: Go into the report studio editor and choose show generated SQL from the button near the top right hand corner.  Copy the SQL and compare it to your native sql query, especially the where clause. It's probable that what you think you've generated in your query isn't the same as your native query.

Also, systematically remove prompts from your report to identify which filter is causing the problem (although you can do that via the show generated SQL method too).

Comment: Cest Moi is right.   Disable your filters until you get a result is a smart divide and conquer approach.  This could be the result of conflicting filters.  For example Company = 1 and Company =2 will result in no data available.  Instead Company = 1 OR Company = 2.

If you can share the SQL or an abstracted version of it, we might be able to help a little more.  Also a classic issue with No Data Available is the type of join.  If it is an inner join to a table where you assumed data would be (but in fact there isn't a record), that may be your culprit.